# Finding average weight of edges in unidirectional graph

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to produce easier-to-parse graph from an interactions table:

from
interactions

```
from | to | weight
1    | 2  | 3
2    | 1  | 2
3    | 1  | 4
1    | 4  | 2
2    | 4  | 4
2    | 3  | 5
3    | 2  | 1
```

to
interactions

```
from | to | average weight
1    | 2  | 2.5
1    | 3  | 4
1    | 4  | 2
2    | 4  | 4
2    | 3  | 3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick here is to turn the directional information you have into undirectional information. Let's decide that out "side1" node will always be the smaller one and the "side2" will always be the larger (note that I'm purposefully not calling them "to" and "from", as this would imply directionallity). This logic can be achieved by using `LEAST` and `GREATEST`. Once that's achieved, it's a simple matter of using `AVG` in a grouped query:

```
SELECT   side1, side2, AVG(weight) 
FROM     (SELECT LEAST(to, from) AS side1, GREATEST(to, from) AS side2, weight
          FROM   my_table)
GROUP BY side1, side2
```